# Changing the definition of N: unexpected $RecursionLimit::reclim error

Tags: numerics, core-language, built-in-symbols

I have some objects represented as follows:

```
Object[data, param]
```

`data` is a list of numbers, `param` is an integer.

Somewhere in my program, I need to do something like that:

```
pseed = N[seed, prec];
```

In this context, `seed` can be either a number or my object `Object`. When `seed` is an `Object` I want `N` to be applied only to `data` list. But `N` is applied to `param` too, which I want always to be an Integer.

Of course, I could write:

```
pseed = If[Head[seed] === Object,
  MapAt[N[#, prec]&, seed, 1],
  N[seed, prec]
];
```

But I believe, this would make my code messy and hard to read. Therefore I decided to do something like that:

```
Unprotect[N];
N[Object[data_List, param_Integer], p_] := Object[N[data, p], param];
Protect[N];
```

Than the simple `N[seed, prec]` should work whether `seed` is `Obj` or `Number`. However, I get the following error:

```
$RecursionLimit::reclim: Recursion depth of 1024 exceeded.
```

I cannot understand, where do I have a recursion?

Thanks in advance!

---

**Update.** I have received the answer from Wolfram Support:

> I understand you believe you've found a bug with N.
>
> In this case, Mathematica is behaving as designed. N is a fairly complicated function and changing its definition arbitrarily by using the Unprotect function can lead to unforeseen consequences. While the definition we provide works as designed, the change you made to it does not behave as you expect. The TagSet and TagSetDelayed function was supplied to address just the kind of problem you are trying to solve. Try
>
> ```
> In[1]:= f/:Verbatim[N][f[arg1_,otherArgs__]]:=f[N[arg1],otherArgs]
> In[2]:= N[f[1,2]]
> Out[2]= f[1.,2]
> ```
>
> Alternatively, you can avoid the need for the Verbatim function by injecting a secondary step:
>
> ```
> In[1]:= f/:NN[f[arg1_,args__]]:=f[NN[arg1],args]
> In[2]:= NN[arg1_]:=N[arg1]
> In[3]:= NN[f[1,2]]
> Out[3]= f[1.,2]
> ```
>
> Setting up the dummy function can even allow you to avoid the need for the TagSetDelayed:
>
> ```
> In[1]:= NN[f[arg1_,args__]]:=f[N[arg1],args]
> In[2]:= NN[f[1,2]]
> Out[2]= f[1.,2]
> ```
>
> For more on TagSet, TagSetDelayed and Verbatim, please see
>
> http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TagSet.html
>
> http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TagSetDelayed.html

The question seems to be solved. Thank everybody for participation!

Comment: Why don't define it explicitly? `pSeedFunc[data_Object, prec_?NumericQ] := Sequence[data, N@prec]; 
pSeedFunc[nbr_?NumericQ, prec_?NumericQ] := 
 Sequence[N@nbr, N@prec]; pSeedFunc[Object[caca, 1], 1]`

Comment: @belisarius Oh, I haven't thought about that! Actually, it would solve my problem, but I have many places in my code, where I need to take `N` from an `Object` or `Number` (not only in the given example). That's why I would like to add my own definition of function `N`.

Comment: @Melkogotto I changed the title of the question to emphasize the essence of the problem. If you think it is inappropriate, you can rollback the edit.

Comment: @Melkogotto It seems you have discovered a long-standing bug in `N`. I suggest you to report it to the technical support (with a link to this thread). I have added the `bugs` tag.

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov I've reported the issue. I let you know, when I'll receive support answer.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The recursion limit error which you observe looks like a bug in `N`. Here is a shorter code to reproduce the issue:

```
N[obj[args__]] := obj[args]    
N@obj[1, 2, 3]
```

> ```
> During evaluation of In[2]:= $RecursionLimit::reclim: Recursion depth of 1024 exceeded. >>
>
> obj[1, 2, 3]
> ```

In the comments [Oleksandr R.](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/312/oleksandr-r) [provided](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/66809/changing-the-definition-of-n-unexpected-recursionlimitreclim-error#comment186774_66817) a workaround via combined usage of `Verbatim` and `UpValues`:

```
ClearAll[Object];
Object /: 
 Verbatim[N][Object[arg1_, arg2_, argRest__], 
  Narg : _ | PatternSequence[]] := 
 Object[arg1, N[arg2, Narg], argRest]
```

---

If you wish `N` to affect only the first argument of `Object`, it is sufficient just to set the `NHoldRest` attribute:

```
ClearAll[Object];
SetAttributes[Object, NHoldRest]
```

Now

```
N@Object[1, 1]
```

> ```
> Object[1., 1]
> ```

Comment: Wow, what a nice attribute! This will probably solve my problem.
Don't you know, what can I do, if my `data` list is somewhere between other parameters, like: `Object[param1, data, param2]`? I can place my list at the first place in `Object`, but maybe I can somehow avoid this.

Comment: In this case you will not have such a simple and elegant solution and probably will need to go through `UpValues` in a way similar to what you showed in your question. Other way is shown by @belisarius in his [comment](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/66809/changing-the-definition-of-n/66817#comment186707_66809).

Comment: Can you explain a lit bit more about `UpValues`? I'm afraid, I haven't understood you.

Comment: Sorry for disinformation but with `UpValues` I get the recursion limit error too. The idea was: `Object /: N[Object[arg1_, arg2_, argRest__]] := Object[arg1, N@arg2, argRest]`. I do not know why with `N` this gives the recursion limit error, it does work with other heads.

Comment: `Object /: Verbatim[N][Object[arg1_, arg2_, argRest__]] := 
 Object[arg1, N[arg2], argRest]`

Comment: @OleksandrR. It works, thank you. Do you have any idea why the recursion limit error appears without `Verbatim`?

Comment: The `Trace` is not very enlightening, but I think this may have to do with the recursive behavior of `N`. When called on any expression, it applies itself to the parts first (and the parts of the parts, &c.) in an effort to numericize the whole. Here it seems that it gets stuck while repeatedly trying to numericize the second argument. Possibly a bug in `N`? By the way, a better pattern is `Object /: Verbatim[N][Object[arg1_, arg2_, argRest__], Narg : _ | PatternSequence[]] := Object[arg1, N[arg2, Narg], argRest]`. This handles the argument of `N` correctly.

Comment: @OleksandrR. I tried to set the `NHoldAll` attribute for `Object` but it does not help. Looks like a bug indeed.

Comment: @OleksandrR. I included your workaround in my answer. If you post your own answer, I'll delete the corresponding part of mine.